How to use Tauri Resource Files properly on Android
I'm currently trying to write an android app using tauri that is required to access font resource files.

I added these files in my src-tauri directory within a fonts folder.
In my tauri.conf.json I set the "bundle": {"resources": ["fonts/*"]} specifier
I checked the targe > debug directories and the fonts folder + font files were all created

However, when trying to access the file using following code snippet, I get a NotFound error.
let resource_path = app_handle
        .path()
        .resolve(format!("fonts/{}", name), BaseDirectory::Resource)
        .expect("failed to resolve resource");
let mut file = File::open(&resource_path).expect(&format!("Failed to open font file {}", resource_path.as_path().to_str().unwrap()));

10-19 16:22:58.189 19486 19600 I RustStdoutStderr: thread '<unnamed>' panicked at src\lib.rs:85:47:
10-19 16:22:58.189 19486 19600 I RustStdoutStderr: Failed to open font file asset://localhost/fonts/Calibri-Regular.ttf: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }

I tried the same code on windows and everything worked fine, android seems to handle resources differently, but I normally do not develop android applications, so I'm not sure how to approach this. Any help is appreciated :)
